# UINavigationController Custom transition issue

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I followed many tutorials about how to create custom transitions but most of them apply to the presentation and dismissing of the view controllers. I just want to apply custom transitions to the UINavigationController for the push/pop actions.

After reading apple documentation I created simple project to test if it works.

Here is all my code for custom Navigation Controller:

```
class CustomNC: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }
}

extension CustomNC: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(
        navigationController: UINavigationController,
        animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation,
        fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController,
        toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

        print("Creating UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning for operation: \(operation.rawValue)")
        return self
    }
}

extension CustomNC: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        print("Returning duration for transition")
        return 1.0
    }
    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        print("Animating transition")
        let container = transitionContext.containerView()!
        let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
        let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

        // set up from 2D transforms that we'll use in the animation
        let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container.frame.width, 0)
        let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-container.frame.width, 0)

        // start the toView to the right of the screen
        toView.transform = offScreenRight

        // add the both views to our view controller
        container.addSubview(toView)
        container.addSubview(fromView)

        // get the duration of the animation
        // DON'T just type '0.5s' -- the reason why won't make sense until the next post
        // but for now it's important to just follow this approach
        let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

        // perform the animation!
        // for this example, just slid both fromView and toView to the left at the same time
        // meaning fromView is pushed off the screen and toView slides into view
        // we also use the block animation usingSpringWithDamping for a little bounce
        UIView.animateWithDuration(
            duration,
            delay: 0.0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
            initialSpringVelocity: 0.8,
            options: [],
            animations: {
                fromView.transform = offScreenLeft
                toView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            }, completion: { finished in
                // tell our transitionContext object that we've finished animating
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })
    }
}
```

Then I simply create two default view controllers First and Second. First has UIButton with show action to the Second. First is embedded in NavigationController and this NavigationController has Custom Class set to CustomNC.

[image: My Storyboard]

After running I see V1 controller but when I tap UIButton application crash without any error message. In Logs I see only those lines:

```
Creating UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning for operation: 1
Returning duration for transition
(lldb)
```

So as I understand the delegate is visible and navigation controller is using this delegate properly. When transition starts it gets the animation duration time interval but animateTransition method is never called because I don't see "Animating transition" message in log.

Can somebody point me where I have problem?

Comment: are you testing on a device or simulator? If you're testing on a device try simulator, the errors tend to be more precise. Methods itself seem to be finde. Are you sure a navigationcontroller can be it's own delegate and  animationController?

Comment: I'll try on simulator. No I'm not sure that navigation controller can be it's own delegate but I'll try to separate it.

Comment: Can definitely be it's own delegate but maybe not animationController. This is usually a seperate object which also allows you to reuse it

Comment: NavigationController can be it's own delegate but the object that comforms to protocol: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning must be separate object so @matteok has a good intuition in this topic. I created separate class and it is working now :) I can continue digging in to this topic now. Thank You!